# How does the stack_overflow() function work?

Tags: c

So I just came to the part in my book where stacks are explained. Here's how they get defined in my book (code):

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 100

int contents[STAC_SIZE]
int top = 0;

void make_empty(void){
    top = 0;
}

bool is_empty(void){
    return top == 0;
}

bool is_full(void){
    return top == STACK_SIZE;
}

void push(int i){
    if(is_full()){
        stack_overflow();
    }
    else{
        contents[top++] = I;
    }

int pop(void){
    if(is_empty()){
        stack_underflow();
    }
    else{
        return contents[--top];
    }
}
```

I don't get 2 things here:

- how can the `make_empty()` function work? By just initializing `top` to 0, `contents` has still all its elements loaded in... shouldn't `contents` be initialized as well?
- what do the 2 `stack_overflow()` and `stack_underflow()` functions do? Is their behavior defined by default in `stdio.h`? If so, what happens when they get called? If not, am I supposed to define them by myself?

Also, just out of curiosity, is there a library that defines all the stack functions already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can the make_empty() function work?

Think about it this way: What effect do you expect `make_empty` to have? Well, to empty the stack obviously, but what does that mean in terms of the interface we have? A couple of things:

- After emptying the stack, `is_empty` should be true. Does setting `top = 0` accomplish that? Yes, because `is_empty` just checks that `top == 0`.
- After emptying the stack, popping it should cause an underflow. Does setting `top = 0` accomplish that? Yes, because `pop` will cause an underflow if `is_empty` is true, which it will be.
- After emptying the stack, we should be able to push `STACK_SIZE` times before we get an overflow. Does setting `top = 0` accomplish that? Yes, because `push` increases `top` by one each time and won't cause an overflow until `top == STACK_SIZE`. So if `top` is zero, we can push `STACK_SIZE` times.

> By just initializing top to 0, contents has still all its elements loaded in... shouldn't contents be initialized as well?

To what? An array of size 0? We can't do that because `contents` has been declared to have size `STACK_SIZE`, not 0. An array's size is fixed and can never change.

We could set all of the elements to 0, but that wouldn't actually accomplish anything. The values of the elements with index `>= top` will never affect anything, so why bother changing them?

> what do the 2 stack_overflow() and stack_underflow() functions do?

Presumably they're supposed to tell the user that an over- or underflow has occurred and then exit the application or invoke some sort of error handler.

> Is their behavior defined by default in stdio.h?

No.

> If not, am I supposed to define them by myself?

Presumably.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions in order:

1. `make_empty()` works like that because the `push()` function puts an element at the current `top` of the stack. Yes, `contents` still has the old values from the stack, however this is not important because they will be overwritten.
2. I think that `stack_overflow()` and `stack_underflow()` are put there just to illustrate what the normal behavior is when a push is made on a full stack, or a pop on an empty stack. They are not implemented in stdio.h. If you really want, you can create them yourself and include a printf, such as

   ```
   void stack_overflow()
   {
      printf("Stack Overflow! The program will crash!");
      exit(1); //this function exits the program. It is defined in stdlib.h
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The `top` variable tells the implementation where the top of the stack is, or, equivalently, how many elements it contains.  That speaks to the *logical* contents, not the physical memory the stack occupies.  Because this implementation uses an array to store the stack elements, every available position will always have some value stored in it.  The key question is *which correspond to* bona fide *stack elements*, and that's exactly what `top` describes.  Thus, `make_empty()` works by adjusting `top` to say that the stack storage contains no actual stack elements.  The whole storage is available for elements.

The `stack_overflow()` and `stack_underflow()` are not standard functions.  The names appear to be intended to convey the idea that a stack overflow or stack underflow occurs in that situation, without specifying any particular behavior.

A real-world implementation might implement those to emit a diagnostic message, return an error code (if the implementation provided for that, which the example doesn't), terminate, or, if it were a bit shoddy, commence undefined behavior in those cases.  In the overflow case, there might also be the potential to expand the stack, but the details of your particular example do not make that a possibility.